# How can I run "echo $?" in clojure through clojure.java.shell?

Tags: clojure

I try to do it like:

```
(shell/sh "echo" '"$?")
```

However, it returns

```
{:exit 0, :out "$?\n", :err ""}
```

So how can I give $? as an argument but string to "echo" with clojure.java.shell?

Comment: What did you expect the output would be?

Comment: In my case, the command run in shell is: echo "$?". But what I really want to do is: echo $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it's not possible to get what you want with shell/sh.

- When you run **echo $?** in the shell, the shell rewrites it into **echo 0** (assuming that the last command is successful).
- when you run shell/sh, it just invokes the **Runtime.exec(["echo" '"$?"]) in background. $? is passed to echo and echo has no idea what $ means.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a command in Bash, the return value of the program will be bound to `$?`. It means that when you execute `echo "$?"` in bash it will replace `$?` with the last return value and only then call the `echo` command. It is internal to bash (and bash-like shells) and not available in other programming language such as Java or Clojure.

Clojure's `clojure.java.shell/sh` basically calls `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`. The return value will be under the `:exit` key of the returned map.

An example to a **successful** sh call:

```
(clojure.java.shell/sh "ls" "target")
=>
{:exit 0, :out "classes\nrepl-port\nstale\n", :err ""}
```

An **unsuccessfull** call:

```
(clojure.java.shell/sh "ls" "nothing")
=>
{:exit 2, :out "", :err "ls: cannot access 'nothing': No such file or directory\n"}
```

Comment: I'm just curious about how can I run echo $? with clojure.java.shell/sh

Comment: what output do you expect from running "echo $?".

Comment: {:exit 0, :out "0", :err ""} ：out should be the last exit value in shell